# Why Is 0.35+0.05 Equal to 0.39999999999999997 (Recuring Number) In JS?

Tags: javascript, numbers, sum

In a Javascript code of mine, I've noticed that the result of **0.35+0.05** is **0.39999999999999997** which is a Recurring Decimal, why?

Comment: IEEE754 strikes again...

Comment: wow what a fast answering comment

Comment: Is there some reason why the half-billion _other_ questions on SO about floating-point imprecision didn't clear it up for you? :-)

Comment: Because they have different titles, not refering to "Recurring Decimal"